# How do I get rid of vim-latex's output from PDF viewing?

Tags: pdf, editors, viewers, vim, evince

I use vim with [VIM-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/). I can use `\ll` to compile and `\lv` to view. I've set the following options in my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
```

When I type `\lv`, it opens the (previously generated) PDF in evince, as desired. However, when I quit evince, my vim window (not the buffer itself) is overwritten with some of evince's exit messages. For example, with a window like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
~
~
```

pressing `\lv` and then quitting evince yields this:

[image: Example of weird buffer action]

Running `:redraw!` fixes it, but `:redraw` doesn't.

How can I prevent this behavior?

<sup>I've found a solution but would like to know if there's a better one.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to the `.vimrc` fixes it:

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf='evince 2>/dev/null'
```

This redirects evince's error stream to the "black hole" device file.

Comment: I get this error even if I open evince from the terminal, which doesn't get fixed by this. What can I do in that case?

Comment: @KonradHöffner: It’s not really a problem at a terminal, because you’re in cooked mode, but you can still run `evince foo.pdf 2>/dev/null`.